# Including multiple authors using HTML meta tags, and how to ensure Google use meta description instead of page content

Tags: html, search-engine, meta-tags

I have two questions regarding meta data in an HTML/PHP file:

1. How can I include multiple authors?
2. I have provided my website with a meta description, but on Google it displays the content of the page as a result. Is there something else I should add?

Comment: These are two separate questions that are only vaguely related and should be represented as two questions, not a single long question with multiple parts.

Answer (score 12):

> How can i include multiple authors?

There is no standard for author meta data, so however you like. A comma separated list, or multiple meta elements strike me an obvious solutions. The primary audiences for that meta data are likely to be humans reading the source and any tools you run over your own documents.

> I have provided my website with a meta description, but on Google it displays the content of the page as a result… is there something else I should add?

No. Either Google hasn't picked up the new meta data yet, or it has decided that content from the page provides a better summary for that search.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
<meta name="author" content="co-authored by john smith, jane Beu,Jack Foo">
```

For Google meta description is enough.

Comment: where's the source?